# Passing an interceptor to retrofit builder using dagger-hilt

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm learning about retrofit interceptors, for work purposes I'm using dagger-hilt for the injection of dependencies to fragments etc. I wrote a custom interceptor to check for connection errors and I'm trying to add it to the `Retrofit.Builder()`:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApi(): StoreApi {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(StoreApi::class.java)
    }
```

however, I have no clue how to pass that:

```
     val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
                .newBuilder()
                .addInterceptor(ConnectivityInterceptor)
                .build()
```

as a .client() to the retofit builder (even with dagger-hilt), any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can setup a module something like this where you provide all the dependency requirements as functions and exposing them to dagger through `@Provides` then leave dagger to provide the dependencies as function arguments to build the dependency graph :

```
@Module class ApiModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideApi(retrofit: Retrofit): StoreApi {
        return retrofit
            .create(StoreApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun retrofit(client: OkHttpClient): Retrofit =
       Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun client(connectivityInterceptor: ConnectivityInterceptor): OkHttpClient =
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(connectivityInterceptor)
            .build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun interceptor(): ConnectivityInterceptor = ConnectivityInterceptor()
}
```

This is a trivial example based on the supplied code.

Comment: yea, that's some random  java code that was similar to the production code, so forgive me for the "new" and other random "bugs" ;), thanks for the solution tho :D